# Conceptual differences between urgent, emergency, planned, unplanned, elective and acute care

Tags: terminology, emergency

I have a bunch of health care terms between which I would like to disambiguate the relationships. A concept map or diagram would be really appreciated since I think better that way. Terms are:

- Emergency care
- Urgent care
- Non-elective
- Acute care
- Elective care
- Planned care